# creating global variables causes linker error

Tags: c++, mfc, linker, compiler-errors, global-variables

I have an MFC application AVT_testapp, and in the header file (AVT_testappDlg.h) I am trying to create a variable outside of all functions, classes, etc. in order to make it global.  Whenever I try to do this though (say I try `int x = 7`), I get the error:

```
1>AVT_testappDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int x" (?x@@3HA) already defined in 
    AVT_testapp.obj
1>..\..\bin\x64\Debug\AVT_testapp.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more 
    multiply defined symbols found
```

***Everything I have found on google says "just add header guards".***  AVT_testappDlg has 6  #include's, and each of them has header guards.

What else could be causing these errors when creating global variables?

EDIT:  Here is the beginning of my header file,

```
#pragma once

#include "../../src/CoreUtils/nierr.h"
#include "..\..\src\CoreUtils\StringHelpers.h" //includes windows.h
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "IFrameObserver.h"
#include "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\GdiPlusHeaders.h"
//#include <fstream>
//#include <windows.h>

int x = 7;

using namespace AVT::VmbAPI;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////  MyObserver class   ///////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class MyObserver : public IFrameObserver
{
private:
    MyObserver( MyObserver& );

    MyObserver& operator=( const MyObserver& );    

public:

    VmbUchar_t* imageData;

            //...
            //...
            //...
            //...

//that's the end of the relevant stuff
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot *define* variables at namespace level in a header. In general it is best not to have global variables, but if you need to you should provide only a *declaration* in the header and the definition in a single .cpp:

```
//header
extern int i;

//cpp
int i;
```

The problem with your code is not related to header guards. Header guards ensure that a header is parsed only once in each translation unit. Lack of header guards causes *compiler* errors, where the compiler sees, say for example a class, defined multiple times in the same translation unit after preprocessing. In your case the error is a linker error *LNK2005*, and it means that the same symbol was defined in multiple translation units (in your case in each translation unit that includes the header with the definition).

Comment: changing `int i = 7;` to just `extern int i;` did not get rid of the errors

Comment: @xcdemon05 Did you rebuild all affected .cpp files? And are you getting the *same* errors?

Comment: Oops sorry I accidentally deleted my comment after that last one but yeah I fixed it

Answer (score 6):

If the global variable is not `const`(*), you cannot put it in a header file and include it in multiple translation units (i.e. `.cpp` files). Otherwise, you will end up with multiple definitions of the same symbol in your program, violating the **ODR** (**One Definition Rule**, see Paragraph 3.2 of the C++11 Standard), and the linker will complain about that.

You should use the `extern` modifier in your shared header to provide only a declaration of your variable:

```
extern int var;
```

Then, in **one single** `.cpp` file, you can provide a definition for it:

```
int var;
```

(*) `const` global variables have internal linkage by default, so each translation unit will end up having a private copy of it and no multiple definition will occur.

Answer (score 3):

if you insist on having a global variable at least put it in a namespace to avoid collisions with other modules

```
namespace globals
{
  extern int x;
}
```

then in the .cpp file define it.

```
int globals::x = 0;
```

it also makes it more clear that it is a global variable.