# zlib - Linking globals named '_dist_code': symbol multiply defined

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV from a build created using crosscompilation c , c++ libraries (emscripten).

I have come across this website which points out a similar issue with zlib while including external libs on Android.
http://www.shiva-engine.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=27858

He mentions a list of conflicting symbols -

```
z_errmsg
zcfree
zcalloc
_tr_init
_tr_tally
_length_code
_dist_code
_tr_align
_tr_stored_block
_tr_flush_block
inflate_table
inflate_copyright
```

The error mentions global variables multiply defined for the above variables.

The link above tells me to change the variable name in .h files and calls it as a dirty hack.

I tried to change variable name in the tree.h file. Also tried to add an `extern` before the name as per this [creating global variables causes linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855915/creating-global-variables-causes-linker-error). But the error simply changes to `Linking globals named 'my_new_variable_name'` or with extern it shows the same error.

```
const uch ZLIB_INTERNAL _dist_code[DIST_CODE_LEN] ={
..
..}
```

Anyone who can understand the link or how I must rename or use extern to resolve the issue and give me a direction would be immensely helpful. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error specific to zlib, similar to what they've said here http://www.shiva-engine.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=27858 , I've found something similar working for me.

There seem to be three files namely trees.h , trees.c and deflate.h where _dist_code is defined.

As a temporary fix only for this case, I've just called all the variables along with this one which give a problem in `.h` files as static.

```
static uch ZLIB_INTERNAL _dist_code[DIST_CODE_LEN] ={
..
..}
```

For more problems later I just commented all the options for sse in OpenCV CmakeLists.txt file to remove the SIMD errors.

Hope this helps someone. Any better solution is welcome.